# ハッシュ値の持ち方について

Tags: database

パスワードなどのハッシュ値をDBで持とうと思っているのですが、
通常のデータベースではハッシュ値はどのような型で扱うべきなのでしょうか？

ちなみにオラクル12cを使用しております。
RAW型で持つのが一般的なのでしょうか？
それともハッシュ値を16進数表記の文字列にしてCHAR型等で持つべきでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

人力でINSERT、UPDATEするケースを考慮して、16進数表記の文字列にしてCHAR型で持つのが便利かと思います。(`sha512sum`等のコマンドの出力を使えるといった点も考慮して)

Answer (score 1):

用途に依るのではないでしょうか。
頻繁にもしくは積極的に表示を行うのであればCHAR等の文字列型の方が効率がいいでしょう。
一致比較を主とするのであればRAW等のバイナリ型の方が効率がいいでしょう。

Answer (score 1):

私ならBASE64なりHEX表記の文字列で格納します。データベース保守ツールはRAW/BLOBデータの扱いに制約があるものが少なくなく、開発言語を問わずRAW/BLOBを扱うのは一手間増える事が多いからです。もちろんデータサイズが増えるなどのデメリットもありますが、格納するのがハッシュ値であるなら最大でも1KB程度に過ぎず、十分に許容できるサイズと考えています。